# Статическая функция, считающая кол-во объектов

Tags: visual-c++

Здравствуйте! Создаю класс, считающий количество объектов этого класса. В нем есть есть статическое поле и статический метод:

```
class gamma
{
private:
    //всего объектов класса(только объявление), 
    //по идее, должен инициализироваться нулем
    static int total; 
    int id; //ID текущего объекта
public:
gamma()//конструктор без аргументов
{
    total++; //добавить объект
    id = total; //id равен текущему значению total
}
~gamma() //деструктор
{
    total--;
    cout << "Удаление ID " << id << endl;
}
static void showtotal() // статическая функция
{
    cout << "Всего: " << total << endl;
}
void showid()  //не статическая функция
{
    cout << "ID: " << id << endl;
}
};
```

При создании объекта этого класса в  main () компилятор выдает "Ошибка средств компоновщика LNK2001".

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    gamma obj;
    return 0;
}
```

в справке говорится  "В коде присутствует ссылка на что-то (функцию, переменную, метку), что не может быть найдено компоновщиком в библиотеках или объектных файлах".

Я предполагаю, что проблема в total (не инициализируется нулем)
Как можно в явной форме инициализировать total нулем?

Или проблема в чем-то другом?

Спасибо.

Comment: Лучше использовать фабрику. Иначе рискуете нарваться на жуткие глюки. Ну и int вместо size_t для подсчета - глупость великая есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class gamma
{
private:
    //всего объектов класса(только объявление), 
    //по идее, должен инициализироваться нулем
    static int total;
```

Здесь только декларируется, что такое поле у класса существует. Само по себе статическое поле не создаётся при создании экземпляра класса, поэтому и:

```
В коде присутствует ссылка на что-то (функцию, переменную, метку), что
не может быть найдено компоновщиком в библиотеках или объектных файлах
```

Его нужно создавать отдельно, причём вне определения класса:

```
/* ---- gamma.cpp ---- */
int gamma::total = 0;
```